# XSLT calling java embedded with XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt, tags

I've got an xsl snippet:

```
<GOGO>
     <xsl:variable name="test">
        <xsl:copy-of select="response"/>
     </xsl:variable>
     <xsl:copy-of select="javamap:echo($test)"/>
</GOGO>
```

This snippet calls a java method:

```
public static String echo(String a) {
    System.out.println("HERE I AM:"+a+":");
    return "<xxx>" + a + "</xxx>";
}
```

If I just have the following snippet:

```
<GOGO>
<xsl:copy-of select="response"/>
</GOGO>
```

the result transformation will soemthing like:

```
<foo>val1</foo>
<bar>val2</bar>
```

However when the Java method is invoked, the system out output is unexpected only printing out:

```
val1
val2
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I get java method to output the expected xml snippet?

EDIT: 
Answer to questions from those helping me:
I am using Saxon9. 
Someone in another thread showed me the use of value-of and disable-output-escaping="yes" which allowed me to print out the xxx element tag in the output. However I am still stumped on the input side where I would like my java class to have full awareness of the full xml snippet I pass to it.

The foo and bar tags are the xml I want to pass into the java function. Inside the java function I want to further wrap the xml in xxx tag.

EDIT 2:
Hints below allowed me to derive the following solution:
    public static String echo(Node a) throws Exception {

```
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(a), new StreamResult(writer));
    String xml = writer.toString();
    return xml;
}
```

Comment: well. I can guess one reason, you are passing a node set but reading it as string! When function reads it as an argument as a string, only value(text) is loaded!

Comment: give a try defining a as node-set rather than string! Then convert it to string (hope innerHTML would turn nodeset to XML) .. Don't know if it works but worth giving a try!

Comment: If the comment above does solve this, let us know so its author can post it as an answer. If it does not work, then providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) might help you to get an answer on this. I for one find your question slightly confusing, e.g. because your function writes `xxx` but your output `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: your hint gave me a direction and i am posting the solution in my EDITs

Answer (score 2):

The semantics of extension functions depend on the processor you are using, which you haven't told us, but I think it would be highly unlikely for any processor to work the way you expect - that is, to treat the string returned by a function as lexical XML to be parsed and turned into a node. If you want to return a node, you must construct a node before returning it. The kind of node (eg. whether it's a DOM node, what document it belongs to etc) will be system-dependent; and on the whole I would recommend NOT manipulating nodes in extension functions - XSLT does the job much better.